# Complete Binary Tree

Tags: binary-trees

[R C Lacher's definition](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Elacher/lectures/Output/trees_intro/slide08.html):

> A binary tree is complete iff the only vertices with less than two children are in the bottom two layers.

[Paul E. Black's definition](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/completeBinaryTree.html):

> A binary tree in which every level (depth), except possibly the deepest, is completely filled. At depth n, the height of the tree, all nodes must be as far left as possible.

Which one is more accurate?

I know these definitions can vary from author to author, but what could be the underlying philosophy for this variation?

Comment: Find a tree complete by one definition, but not by the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider Paul E. Black's definition. As per that,

```
              This is a complete binary tree                 This is not
                            2     ---------depth 0---------       2
                          /   \                                 /   \
                         1     3  ---------depth 1---------    1     3
                       /  \   /                              /  \     \
                      4    5 8    ---------depth 2--------- 4    5     8
                        tree 1                                tree 2
```

but as per R C Lacher's definition, they both are valid. If a definition is to be followed, I'd say follow the one which is more strict, as it leaves less room for ambiguity in understanding it. When you say the elements are a filled as left as possible you get only $1$ tree(in terms of positions of nodes) but if you allow freedom at the last level, where you have $n$ positions and $k$ nodes, you have $\binom{n}{k}$ complete binary trees.

As for the philosophy, I believe Paul's definition seems more relevant to suit to the array representation of a binary tree. Where you perform the level order traversal of the tree and store the elements sequentially in an array. If you try to store a tree following Lacher's definition, chances are you'll end up having empty slots in the array representation, which isn't a good thing for arrays.